# Focing printing of tensor's actual rows and columns (not a ',' in shape)

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, tensor

I am new to Tensor flow.

How do I get a simple `print` of a `tensorflow.shape` to print both rows and columns.
For example:

```
print (tf.shape(test))
```

prints `Tensor("Shape_33:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)`

I want the `shape` attribute to print both the `rows` and `columns` (the actual numbers). Is there a way to force this?

Second: This tensor in my code has shape (3, 128). The `shape` returned above shows 2 rows. The correct number of rows would have been 3..

Answer (score 0):

`tf.shape` returns a tensor representing the shape of the input tensor. In your example, `test` is a tensor that is of shape `(3, 128)`. Calling `tf.shape(test)` returns a tensor that holds `(3, 128)` which is why the shape of it is `(2,)`. Regarding printing actual values, doing `print(test)` or `print(test.numpy())` should work.

Comment: One thing is not clear to me. If the shape of the matrix (`test` is my example) is `3*128`, why does `tf.shape` return `(2,)`. `tf.shape` should just return `(3, 128)`. Second, how can I get the returned shape to print the actual number of rows and actual number of columns.

Comment: Try setting the result of `tf.shape(test)` in a variable. Then, print the variable at index 0 and 1. It should print 3 and 128. As above, `tf.shape` returns a tensor holding the value of shape. Not the shape itself. So to get the actual rows and columns, just print each index of the resulting tensor from `tf.shape`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that works. But I don't get the variable at index `1`. For example, I get the `index` at `0` with is `3`. Both of these work for the `index` at `0`:                                               `x = tf.shape(test)
print (x[0].eval())` OR `print ("v4",test.shape )`. But neither works for the index at location `1`. For the `print ("v4",test.shape )`, it just prints `v4 (3,)` and nothing for index `1`. There should a way to force pricing the index at `1` in the for `v4`. For the earlier example, it makes sense to index at `1` (just like we did for `0`, but does not work)

Comment: ` m1, n1 = test.get_shape().as_list()`